# How to delete a date and time tab in setting to prevent user from changing it?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, system, delete

<sup>(Please understand me about my broken English.)</sup>

I am a student in South Korea.

I am making a quite restricted Lenovo tablet, to make it a perfect education device. The goal is to "help" students to study hard.

To do that, I have to prevent the users from changing the system time in the "Settings", Because changing system time is a easy way to pass my time-dependent application block.

So I am trying to delete the date and time menu from the system settings, to keep only auto time:

[image]

By an experience of deleting a guest mode in the system, I think I should use the Buildprop app. But I don't know, what I should delete and change in the system.

Of course it's okay not using Buildprop.

I have a rooted device and my Android version is nougat, 7.1.1.

I'm sorry for using broken English and thanks for reading this. 
Have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Please understand my awkward English (I am writing with an English dictionary.)</sup>

As you can see comments on this question, I have solved this problem by FireLord's help, but it not perfect, because I am not good at Android.

This question is similar to [this.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24061/is-there-a-way-to-disable-access-to-certain-settings-components/185392#185392)  Refer to this first.

*In summary, my simple solution is this:*

1. Using [Settings Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wilco375.settingseditor) (needs Xposed Framework)
2. Using [My Android Tools](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/wangqi/my-android-tools/) or Elixrs 2 apk (needs root permission)
3. pm disable with adb

In my case, a approach of using 'pm disable' with adb is not working.
(adb asks me a correct package name. I command `adb shell pm disable com.android.settings.˜˜˜.`. I don't know correct reason)

And, I can't use the approach of 1. using Settings Editor, because my financial app blocks Xposed Framework.

So I have solved by (2) using my Android tools:

1. - installed apk -> activity menu -> find 'Setting' apk under System tab
2. - disable components you want by toggling these. Such as display, language ...(needed root access)

I think many Setting component is named 'setting$example'.

But *you should learn by trial and error*, disable 10 packages and test by opening Setting apk and again, again to get a result you want. (You should backup first before testing)

In my case, it's easy to hide display, language tab and etc (just disable one proper package).

But the "Date and time" tab is never disabled.

So I disabled 'SystemSettings' (I've hidden the whole system category in the Settings), 'SubSettings' to block approach of all menu from Search in settings (it blocks many Activity. Should check after disable!) and 'SettingActivity' in Clock apk to prevent the appearance of the date and time menu.

It is hard to say a correct and perfect solution because of my broken English and deficient knowledge about Android. What I want to emphasize is this: *you should learn by trial and error*, and then you can get a result what you want.

Thanks for reading and to FireLord.